# iPhone: textViewdDidBeginEditing: textview.tag always 0

Tags: ios, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

In my application, I've written a cycle to assign tag to my textviews:

```
for(j = 0; j<9; j++)
    for(k = 0; k<9; k++) {
        UITextView*txtview =
        [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,25,25)];
        txtview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        txtview.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        txtview.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"TrebuchetMS-Bold" size:18];
        txtview.tag = 10*k + j;
        txtview.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
        [self.view addSubview:txtview];
        [txtview sizeToFit];
        txtview.delegate = self;
        x = x+40;
        y = y+40;
        NSLog(@"%d",txtview.tag);
    }
```

}

The log at the end of the cycle print properly the just assigned tag.

The problem is that when the method textViewDidBeginEditing is called, if I try to retrieve the textView.tag with another log, it always returns 0.
How can I solve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where are you setting your delegate of the TextView at all? And what handleTap: does?

Comment: How many textViews this code will add on same frame?

Comment: Do you want to add 10 UITextViews? You are actually adding 100 UITextViews here.

Comment: Sorry for the missing parts and the handleTap (that was an old method I've tried to use, now useless). I'm trying to add 81 UITextViews.

Comment: Your code is working at my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than adding the UITapGestureRecognizer, you can set a delgate for UITextView.

Code to do that is as follows.

```
txtview.delegate = self;
```

Now you can listen to the delegate method.

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
   NSLog(@"textView tag is %d",txtview.tag);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use

```
    - (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
```

and set the delegate of `TextView`, because I copied your code and tried myself and it was working.

Answer (score 1):

Change :

```
txtview.tag = 10*k + j;
```

to

```
txtview.tag = j*10 + k;
```